# Why is the venomousness of the inland taipan evaluated?

Tags: xkcd

In [XKCD 761](https://www.explainxkcd.com/wiki/index.php/761:_DFS), the venomousness of the inland taipan is mentioned by Hairy.

In real life, the inland taipan only [occurs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inland_taipan#Distribution_and_habitat) in semi-arid areas in Australia, plus a variety of zoos world-wide.

Possibilities I can think of:

- Biology works differently in XKCD compared to real life. For example, velociraptors exist. Maybe all species exist everywhere.
- XKCD is set in Australia. (Is there anything ruling this out?)
- Hairy either was being sloppy in his research, or was interrupted before it was finished.
- Zoos and/or research institutes failing to contain their organisms is regarded as a possibility (See: Jurassic Park)

Why is the venomousness of the inland taipan evaluated?

Comment: @Closevoters: is XKCD not scifi?

Comment: I would say that [this series](https://xkcd.com/1190/) is sci-fi (set in the far future). The comic you linked to has no obvious sci-fi or fantasy elements. Perhaps only XKCD comics or storylines that have SF/F components are on topic here. But we’re in the middle of the Scope Wars, so you could make a meta post arguing for a different view. And if all XKCD comics are set in the same universe, I don’t know whether that universe is sci-fi or fantasy. _Time_ (linked above) surely is, but it’s set much later than the other comics that I’ve read.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hairy wasn't using any criteria per se to restrict, narrow-down, or sort his lists for his depth-first search. XKCD has done this to emphasis the joke; a real depth-first algorithm should have some means of evaluating that the current branch is a dead end or unlikely to approach a solution.  After all snakebites in general are not a likely medical emergency to be encountered when out on a date. And certainly corn snakes and garter snakes should not be at the top of any list of snakes to be worried about biting you. As ExplainXKCD points out those two snakes are harmless.

So, the inland taipan venomousness was evaluated because Hairy's depth-first search of dating problems has caused him to look up the venomousness of all snakes and put that into a spreadsheet, regardless of how likely or unlikely it is that he will encounter that snake on his date.